# linux kernel config.h

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm starting to learn how to write network device driver from:

http://tldp.org/LDP/LGNET/issue93/bhaskaran.html

In the article, the author compiles his example with:

```
cc -I/usr/src/linux-2.4/include/ -Wall -c rtl8139.c
```

My problem is that I'm using 2.6.35.23-generic and I don't have "config.h" in "/usr/src/linux_headers-2.6.35-23-generic/linux/".

Is this file replaced by another file? Is there any site that gives you information for such changes?

Thanks,
Pete.

Comment: ... Why are you using a 2.4 guide to try to write a 2.6 module?

Comment: My first google search comes up with this one. If you have a good one for network device driver for 2.6, I really want to know. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I just take a look on this, jump directly to network driver and ... It's much more complicated than the 2004 one. Not sure but I may need to start from the beginning of the book...

Answer (score 3):

The article http://tldp.org/LDP/LGNET/issue93/bhaskaran.html in your question is from 2003. I'm afraid the C code of Linux kernel changes too quickly, so the C code snippets and compilation instructions in that article most probably don't apply anymore.

Please also note that the article provides information about the 2.4.x Linux kernel versions, but you're trying to compile its code with a 2.6.x kernel. The 2.4 and 2.6 series are very different both in terms of C code and compilation instructions. My advice: try to find a more recent article (preferably from 2010 or 2009) and example code about the 2.6 series.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is my first try for linux kernel so I'm looking for a simple working example. I never think there are so much changes in the kernel. How naive I am. LOL

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please vote it up (click on the gray triangle pointing upwards above the big number). Later, if you find an answer which is just what you need, accept it.